# iTunes URL in tweet in app

Tags: xcode

In my app, I've got a share button for facebook and twitter etc. I want that people can tweet and post the link of my app, but the app is not yet available in the app store, so i can't have a link to the app.

In some apps there is a link to the app if you are composing a tweet, how do they do that?

Comment: Make your app grab the URL from your own server. Update the code on your server as soon as your app is in the AppStore. Profit.

Comment: Where can i make a free server and how can i connect the app to the server?

Comment: I've searched for it, but how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 pointed out, having that AppStore URL delivered from a server you control would likely be something you would prefer.  Naturally, the first question to pop to mind would be something of the form 'Why do I have to use a server at all? Can't I just code it into my app directly?'

In short form, you are not *required* to use a server, but you may find that the benefits and flexibility it offers you in at the cost of a little more networking code and complexity in your app helpful.  Let's expand on this a bit, by imagining we lived in the perfect world where we knew with 100% accuracy what that AppStore URL would be and that it would never ever change.  We could get away with just coding that URL directly into our app and we would never again have to think about that part of our app -- it would always tweet the correct URL, users would be happy, and you as the developer can turn your attention to more important matters.

Unfortunately, things often don't work perfectly and as software developers we have to consider the ugly edges of reality and write code to handle them gracefully.  Here are just a few of the potential problems with hard-coding a URL:

1. We don't *actually* know the full AppStore URL.
2. Apple may decide to change AppStore URL formats and render old URLs invalid.
3. Despite our best efforts to carefully type the URL into our code, we made a mistake and now we have to issue an update and wait for our app to be reviewed to get a simple typo fixed - Eep!

H2CO3's suggestion to use a server builds likely stems from experience in writing software coupled with developer's inherent risk management driven thought processes -- if there is something I can do to make my software handle these ugly edges more gracefully and make my software more reliable, it may make sense to take the extra time to implement my feature differently to protect it from the shadowy unknowns the future may have in store for my app.

For the sake of a balanced argument against putting the URL on a server:

1. If your users are in a place that has spotty cell or wifi coverage, they may not be able to connect with your server to get the AppStore URL from your server
2. Your server might not be working properly so it can't deliver information to your app when requested.
3. Adding a network request like this can be very easy to do, but also introduces its own set of risks to have to consider (isn't writing software great?)

As indicated above, you *do not need* to make your app snag the URL from a server you control, but you *may* want it to do so. Only you, as the app's developer, can determine what degree of risk you are willing to accept and which of the available options you've researched, invented, or otherwise acquired seem to fit your specific needs the best.

Since I don't know your background, I'm going to stay relatively high level and give you another couple of nudges in some directions you can go and do some additional research:

On the 'setup a server' idea -- you can purchase a hosting account from a number of hosting providers around the Internet or if this is a school or work project you may be able to speak with your IT people to request space for a website.  After you have that setup, you can put a file on that space with a placeholder URL and write some code in your app to connect to your server and read your file (that has your fake URL in it!) the put it into your Tweet.  Once your app is approved, you can change the fake URL on your server with the real one, and your App will work like you want.  For the App part of things, you might look into some of the simple +stringWithContentsOfURL: methods on NSString (though do remember to consider things like what happens if the Internet is down, or if you don't get anything back from your server, etc.!)

On the 'just hard code the URL into the app' idea -- Apple makes some marketing resources available to developers even before they release an app.  Checkout (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html) with an emphasis on the Shortlinks section, and also checkout Technical Q&A 1633 (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1633/_index.html).  Both of these links give you information about how to build a link directly to an application or vendor on the AppStore given just their name(s).  Like before, do remember to consider what happens if you ever decide to rename your app, or if linking elsewhere (or maybe nowhere!) would make more sense.

Hopefully this will help you think a little more about what you are actually trying to achieve, and give you a sense about what other developers think about when faced with decisions like the one you've posed here.

Answer (score 0):

While i agree with Bryan i always avoided using servers for basic things. With ios 5+ you can send tweets from inside the app ( and you can add default tweet (i.e. a link to the app)

Your problem can be solved easily this way : make a short link with the link to the app store ( the link to the app store is formatted like this : `https://itunes.apple.com/app/id <app id>` , and the app id the the one in itunnesconnect under Apple ID )

For example you can make a default tweet like this : " Check out this awesome app!! goo.gl/buya " and then the user can edit it as he wishes.

Also..it's extremely unlikely that Apple will change the format of theyr links...too many users depend on this format to do..a lot of things